# Errno 30] Read-only file system: u'templates/jatin/abcpage/'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am copying the files from one folder to another in app engine django project.

```
source_file = os.listdir('templates/1/')
fileList = ['templates/1/'+filename for filename in source_file]
```

for f in fileList:

```
shutil.copy2(f, 'templates/'+request.user.username+'/abcpage/')
```

I am getting following error:

> IOError at /copy_file/ [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
>   u'templates/jatin/abcpage/'

Exception Value:

> [Errno 30] Read-only file system: u'templates/jatin/abcpage/'
>   Exception Location:   C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py
>   in **init**, line 245

Answer (score 1):

App Engine does not support copying files. Application files, and any other files you upload via `update`, are read-only.